# "AttributeError: 'matrix' object has no attribute 'strftime'" error in numpy python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, strftime

I have a matrix with (72000, 1) dimension. This matrix involves timestamps.

I want to use "strftime" as the following; `strftime("%d/%m/%y")`, in order to get the output something like this: `'11/03/02'`.

I have such a matrix:

```
M = np.matrix([timestamps])
```

And I have used "strftime" in order to convert all the matrix involving timestamps to a matrix involving dates in string types. For this reason, I have used "strftime" as the follwing:

```
M = M.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
```

When I run the code, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'matrix' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

What is the right way of using this function? How can I convert the timestamp matrix to date string matrix?

Comment: So the shape of `M` is `(72000,1)` ?

Comment: I'd suggest reading up on the `np.datetime64` dtype.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message shows you, you cannot do something like `matrix.strftime` . One thing you can do would be to use [`numpy.apply_along_axis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) . Example -

```
np.apply_along_axis((lambda x:[x[0].strftime("%d/%m/%y")]),1,M)
```

Demo -

```
In [58]: M = np.matrix([[datetime.datetime.now()]*5]).T

In [59]: M.shape
Out[59]: (5, 1)

In [60]: np.apply_along_axis((lambda x:[x[0].strftime("%d/%m/%y")]),1,M)
Out[60]:
array([['10/10/15'],
       ['10/10/15'],
       ['10/10/15'],
       ['10/10/15'],
       ['10/10/15']],
      dtype='<U8')
```

---

For the new error you are getting -

> "AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'strftime'"

This means that the objects are not `datetime` objects, so if they are timestamps , you can converting them to datetime first. Example -

```
np.apply_along_axis((lambda x:[datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x[0]).strftime("%d/%m/%y")]),1,M)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Anand, but I have to convert a matrix which involves only timestamps. How can I manage that?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I get this error: "AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'strftime'"

Comment: Try `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp()` to convert to datetime first , example given in answer.