# "AttributeError: 'matrix' object has no attribute 'isocalendar'" in numpy python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a numpy matrix as the following:

```
dates = np.matrix([['09/01/70'], ['10/01/70'], ['11/01/70']])
```

And I want to convert this matrix to a matrix which involves week numbers instead of the dates.

Thanks to "isocalendar()" function in python, you can find the week number of the date.

But when I used the function as the following;

```
weeks = dates.isocalendar()[1],
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'matrix' object has no attribute 'isocalendar'
```

What is the right way of converting the date matrix to datenumber matrix in numpy python?

Comment: Can't you apply the answer you just got in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33055070/attributeerror-matrix-object-has-no-attribute-strftime-error-in-numpy-pyt?  `dates` is a matrix, not `datetime` object.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I think I can apply that.

Comment: I have done something like this, but it doesn't work. np.apply_along_axis((lambda x:[x[0].isocalendar()[1]]),1,dates)

Comment: Are you applying `isocalendar`  to `datetime` objects or to numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `pandas` in this case, converting the matrix into a DataFrame with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dates)
```

Then I'd convert the dates into `datetime` objects:

```
df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0])
```

And then finally apply the `isocalendar()` function:

```
df = df[0].apply(lambda x: x.isocalendar()[1])
```

This returns:

```
0    36
1    40
2    44
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Then you can get an array of this with `df.values` or `df.as_matrix()`. Hope that helps even if it needs the use of a new package.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues: 1) converting strings to datetime objects, 2) iterating over elements of a `matrix`.

You've given us a matrix that contains strings:

```
dates = np.matrix([['09/01/70'], ['10/01/70'], ['11/01/70']])

In [286]: dates
Out[286]: 
matrix([['09/01/70'],
        ['10/01/70'],
        ['11/01/70']], 
       dtype='|S8')
```

Neither the `matrix` nor the strings have datetime functionality.  Those strings have to be converted individually.

```
def getweek(dstr):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(dstr,"%d/%m/%y").isocalendar()[1]

In [288]: getweek("15/10/15")
Out[288]: 42
```

Applying it to the `matrix` is a bit of a bother since I have to index both row and column.

Just be clear about what is going on, lets iterate over the matrix and return both the date string and the week.

```
In [285]: [(x[0,0],getweek(x[0,0])) for x in dates]                    
Out[285]: [('09/01/70', 2), ('10/01/70', 2), ('11/01/70', 2)]
```

`getweek` could be tweaked to work along with `apply_along_axis` as suggested in the answer to your other date question.

Are you using `np.matrix` for a special reason?  Why not `np.array`?  A problem with `matrix` is that it keeps returning another matrix - another 2d object, even if it only has 1 element.

There is a nice way of turning it into a 1d array:

```
In [322]: dates.A1
Out[322]: 
array(['09/01/70', '10/01/70', '11/01/70'], 
      dtype='|S8')
```

With a 1d array:

```
In [293]: dates = np.array(['09/01/70', '10/01/70', '11/01/70'])
In [294]: [(x,getweek(x)) for x in dates]
Out[294]: [('09/01/70', 2), ('10/01/70', 2), ('11/01/70', 2)]
In [295]: np.array([getweek(x) for x in dates])
Out[295]: array([2, 2, 2])
```

Usually date strings like this come from a csv file.  We can use `genfromtxt` and `getweek` to load them

Simulate the file with a text lines, and define `converters` for `genfromtxt`.

```
In [339]: txt=b"""09/01/70
   .....: 10/02/70
   .....: 11/03/70
   .....: """

In [340]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),dtype=None,converters={0:getweek})
Out[340]: array([ 2,  7, 11])
```

---

Here's a way of using `np.datetime64` dtype to get weeks

```
In [350]: txt=b"""1970-09-01
1970-10-15
1970-11-25
1970-01-10"""

In [351]: d=np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),dtype='datetime64[D]')
# load the dates as Days; yyyy-mm-dd is the default format

In [352]: d
Out[352]: array(['1970-09-01', '1970-10-15', '1970-11-25', '1970-01-10'], dtype='datetime64[D]')

In [353]: d.astype('datetime64[W]')-d.astype('datetime64[Y]')    
Out[353]: array([34, 41, 46,  1], dtype='timedelta64[W]')
```

`d.astype('datetime64[W]')` converts day units to weeks - though it displays as the first day of the week

`d.astype('datetime64[Y]'` - is year units, but displays as the start of the year.

Their difference is the number of weeks (0 is a day in the 1st week of the year).  There may be a more compact way of deriving this, but I find this approach instructive.

Comment: hpaulj, thank you for your long answer. The problem is, you have explained a long beneficial answer, but didn't explain how I'm gonna fit it to my answer. I have a column matrix, and I want to get the result as a column matrix.

Comment: `np.matrix([...]).T`?

Comment: There is no other way to do it without "for" like lambda? Because for loop takes so much time.

Comment: It gives the output as I wanted, but the solution is so long, and it takes long time to be processed by CPU. I have bunch of arrays like this, and I don't want to wait for so much time for the solution.

Comment: Have you tried it in the `apply_along_axis` framework?

Comment: Yes, I have tried "apply_along_axis", and it worked hpaulj.