# how to solve object has no attribute 'strftime'

Tags: python, masked-array

I've tried to strftime, but i have AttributeError
Here is the code

```
dater=num2date(datafile.variables['lightning_flash_TAI93_time'][:], start_value_units.units)

        daty=dater.strftime("%Y%m%d")
        date = np.concatenate([date, daty[:]])
```

And error

```
File "ISS_LIS_FlashLoc_Quickview_Python3.py", line 154, in <module>
    main(file_path)
  File "ISS_LIS_FlashLoc_Quickview_Python3.py", line 97, in main
    daty=dater.strftime("%Y%m%d")
AttributeError: 'MaskedArray' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

How i can solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["AttributeError: 'matrix' object has no attribute 'strftime'" error in numpy python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33055070/attributeerror-matrix-object-has-no-attribute-strftime-error-in-numpy-pyt)

Comment: @R_Dax thnx for answer, i saw it but i don't know, how i can convert maskedarray to time

Comment: @R_Dax i've tried this
`dater=num2date(datafile.variables['lightning_flash_TAI93_time'][:], start_value_units.units)

            dater=datetime.datetime.strptime(dater, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
            dater=dater.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
            date = np.concatenate([date, dater[:]])`
but error is still `TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not MaskedArray`

Comment: I personally am not 100% sure how to solve your specific problem, but just wanted to highlight another question on SO that might help.